# Fast access to numpy npz data

Tags: python, numpy, npz-file

I have saved many data files as .npz to save space on storage (`savez_compressed`).  Each file is saved as one array, so when using the numpy load function, it returns the key to a dictionary that contains the array.

How can you store this array as an array instead of a dictionary quickly.

For example:

```
data = []
datum = np.load('file.npz')
key = datum.keys()[0]
data.append([datum[key]])
```

When profiling this, my code spent most of the time using the `get` method for the dictionary.

If it was saved as a .npz file, it doesn't need the `get` method and is much faster.

```
data = []
data.append([np.load('file.npz')])
```

I thought by loading the file, the data is already in memory in both cases.  The `savez_compressed` doesn’t seem to have an option to save as just an array.  Is this possible or is there a way to speed up the loading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`np.load` uses a `np.lib.npyio.NpzFile` class to load `npz` files.  Its doc is:

```
NpzFile(fid)

A dictionary-like object with lazy-loading of files in the zipped
archive provided on construction.

`NpzFile` is used to load files in the NumPy ``.npz`` data archive
format. It assumes that files in the archive have a ".npy" extension,
other files are ignored.

The arrays and file strings are lazily loaded on either
getitem access using ``obj['key']`` or attribute lookup using
``obj.f.key``. A list of all files (without ".npy" extensions) can
be obtained with ``obj.files`` and the ZipFile object itself using
``obj.zip``.
```

I think the last paragraph answers your timeing question.  The data is not loaded until you do the dictionary `get`.  So it isn't just a in-memory dictionary lookup - it's a file load (with uncompress).

Python dictionary lookups are fast - the interpreter is doing all the time when accessing attributes of objects.  And when simply managing the namespace.